# Limit query execution time through Spring

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I need to limit the query execution time to PostgeSQL through the Spring repositories. The javax.persistence.query.timeout and spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.query.timeout properties do not give the desired result. How else can I limit? Spring version 2.6.6 Hibernate 5.4.30 and also used HikariCP

I need to throw exception query if time is longer than given

Comment: what do those things do instead of what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the `timeout` attribute of the `@Tansactional` annotation? For example:

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long>{

  @Transactional(timeout = 600)
  ...
  void getOrUpdateSomething();
}
```

It will throw [TransactionTimedOutException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionTimedOutException.html). The attribute only applies for newly started transactions.